# MySQL - How can I get a foreign key

Tags: mysql

I'm reading Head First SQL and is very confused about the use of foreign key. In chapter 7 it shows an example about creating new table with foreign key as following

```
CREATE TABLE interests(
    int_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    interest VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT my_contacts_contact_id_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (contact_id)
    REFERENCES my_contacts (contact_id)
);
```

If my memory serves me right, it creates table interests with a column contact_id which is the foreign key from my_contacts table. However, while I was reading chapter 8 the book asked us to pull out columns, profession for example, to create a new table for reference. For example,

```
        profession
prof_id (primary key) (parent key)
profession VARCHAR(20)

        my_contacts
contact_id (primary key)
prof_id (foreign key)
```

Where does my_contacts.prof_id come from? Originally my_contacts table had profession column and it somehow turned into profession_id by some kind of magic. Now, I have two tables

```
        profession
prof_id (primary key)
profession VARCHAR(20)

        my_contacts
contact_id (primary key)
profession
```

Do I need to map the profession.prof_id to my_contacts and then drop my_contacts.profession column so I can get a foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering just to address what I believe to be the biggest oversight in your question, which regards what you said here:

> it creates table interests with a column contact_id which is the foreign key from my_contacts table

Adding a foreign key constraint to a MySQL table does *not* create a column.  Rather, you still need to create a column for a foreign key as you would any other column.  So, your `CREATE TABLE` statement should look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE interests (
    int_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    interest VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    contact_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT my_contacts_contact_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (contact_id)
        REFERENCES my_contacts (contact_id)
);
```

Comment: Thanks. So the next step should be mapping the value in my_contacts.contact_id to interests.contact_id to establish relation, right?

Comment: Maybe, if that's your next step.  Make sure that the parent record is inserted first, before you insert any child records which refer to it.